# Let a white navbar cover a form div

Tags: html, css

I want the white navbar to cover the form div when the latter is scrolled to the top. How to achieve this?

**css**

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  ......
}

.info-form {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  ......
}
```

**html**

```
  <div id="root">
    <div>
      <div className="navbar"></div>
      <form className="info-form"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position): sticky;

```
.navbar {
  ...
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: approve the answer would be appreciated if it's helpful for you. @XiLiu

Answer (score 0):

Give it a white background, otherwise it's transparent.

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  ......
}
```